# How do you request access to a project in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, user-permissions

Who is able to request access to Azure DevOps projects in an organisation?? I've been having a look into this due to a couple of requests that have come through today. I can't fathom how other users can see that a project requests to be able to request access.

I had a look with a basic user today who is not a site collection admin or project admin and the list of projects shows only the ones they have been included on and no others.  We had a look in organisation settings and there weren't additional ones.

The requests I had came from Project Admins (perhaps they see something different) but I'm just curious to know a bit more on how it works I can see if I need to change anything anywhere.

Comment: Hi, how about the issue? Does the answer below resolve your question, If yes, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do you request access to a project in Azure DevOps? Who is able to request access to Azure DevOps projects in an organisation?

This is a feature from [Sprint 156 Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2019/sprint-156-update#general-1) called `Request Access` policy. This policy is only available for the Organization which is connected to AAD, and only the users belonging to same tenant as the organization can request the access to the resource that they don't have access to.

**Description:**

*You can now request access to an organization with the new request access UI. If you belong to the same tenant as the Azure DevOps organization that you need access to, the new request access UI will let you notify the administrators of the organization with a justification for why you need access. The administrator(s) will receive an email notification from Azure DevOps with the details of the request. Details will include: email ID of the requestor, target organization name and justification.*

**To manage this behavior:**

See [Disable your organization's Request Access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/disable-request-access-policy?view=azure-devops#disable-request-access-policy). We can enable/disable the `Request Access` policy from `Organization Settings=>Policies` and we can also edit the URL if necessary. (See point4 in above link)

Comment: The bit that I'm still unsure of is how someone who is a member of the organisation already can know of a project they're not invited to and can request access. Unlike a project collection admin, they're only seeing projects that they're a member of when they go into DevOps so how do they get to learn of other projects??

Comment: The user won't see the projects he's not invited to, but he can know the project name if he asks someone who's already in that project. Since the user should know the organization name, then a simple link `https://dev.azure.com/OrgName(he  knows)/ProjectName(Someone in that project told him)` comes. He would see the request access page when trying to navigate to the project he's not invited to.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT when I request URL with the project 404 page keep showing knowing that the project is exists, do we have to configure something else?